# Solving an ODE using shooting method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following ODE for my maths project:

$$ y'' = \frac{\alpha}{2}y^3 - \frac{3}{2}y^2 + y - \frac{3}{x} y'$$

under the following boundary conditions:

$$ y'(0) = 0 \\ y(x) \rightarrow y \_ \equiv 0\ \text{as}\ x \rightarrow \infty $$

As a first step, I converted this problem into a set of coupled ODEs:

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = z \\ \frac{dz}{dx} = \frac{\alpha}{2}y^3 - \frac{3}{2}y^2 + y - \frac{3}{x} z$$

under the following boundary conditions:

$$ z(0) = 0 \\ y(x) \rightarrow y \_ \equiv 0\ \text{as}\ x \rightarrow \infty$$

Next, my source tells me to use the shooting method to convert the BVP into an IVP, which means that I have to use two initial guesses of $ y(0) $ to be able to use the secant method to find the appropriate value of $ y(0) $.

Now, my question is, according to my source, I can avoid the singularity at x = 0 using Taylor expansion as follows:

$$ y(r_{0}) = y_{0} + \frac{1}{16} r_{0}^{2} (2y_{0} - 3y_{0}^{2} + \alpha y_{0}^{3}) $$

I see how you can estimate $ y(r_{0}) $ where $ r_{0} $ is a tiny distance away from the origin, but I don't really see how they derived this expression. Could anyone help me out?

Comment: what is $\alpha$ here?

Comment: $\alpha$ is a user-defined constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close to $x=0$ we have the Taylor expansion

$$y(x) = y(0) + xy'(0) + \frac{y''(0)x^2}{2} + \mathcal{O}(x^3)$$

Now we use the ODE which says that

$$y''(x) = \frac{\alpha}{2}y^3 - \frac{3}{2}y_0^2 + y - \frac{3}{x}y'$$

At $x=0$ the last term above becomes $-3y''(0)$ since

$$y''(0) = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{y'(x)-y'(0)}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{y'(x)}{x}$$

Putting all this togeather gives

$$y''(0) = \frac{\alpha}{2}y_0^3 - \frac{3}{2}y_0^2 + y_0 - 3y''(0)$$

and by solving for $y''(0)$ and inserting this into the Taylor expansion gives us (where we again have used $y'(0)=0$)

$$y(x) = y_0 + \frac{x^2}{16}\left(\alpha y_0^3 - 3y_0^2 + 2y_0\right) + \mathcal{O}(x^3)$$

and by truncating at second order we obtain your expression.

Comment: wow! Thanks! I have been trying to derive this formula for the last couple of weeks, but got stuck. I was wondering if you might help me with a couple of other things. Firstly, I was wondering if the notation y_ means that the value of y tends to 0 from under the x-axis. Also, I was wondering how to tackle the infinity in the boundary condition: what value of x should I choose for the condition x==0 to stop my Runge-Kutta integration?

Comment: @failexam The notation $y_0$ means $y(0)$. By the infinity in the boundary condition I suppose you mean the $\frac{z}{x}$ term. Many options here: 1) start the integration at $x=0$ and use $\frac{z}{x} = \frac{x}{8}(\alpha y_0^3+\ldots)$ (the formula above) when $x<\epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is some small constant (say $10^{-5}$, this is a try and fail thing) and $z/x$ given by, well, $z/x$ otherwise. 2) Start the integration at $x=\epsilon$ and use no approximation (might work). 3) Switch x-coordinate to say $t=\log x$. This usually gives better stability for some problems.

Comment: Another suggestion: I would start out with the simplest integration method, standard forward Euler to start with and then switch over to Runge-Kutta if this does not work / requires extremely small time-steps. Then the code (I'm assuming you are writing code for this yourself) becomes simpler and its easier not to make any coding mistakes. If you are using Math software like Mathematica then solving this is really easy and method 2) above is all you need (i.e. starting the integration at some small $x$ value).

Comment: I am using Runge-Kutta because that's what they use in this paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0511156v1.pdf on pages 6-7. Also, I am writing the code in Java cos my supervisor says writing the code in Mathematica or Matlab will not give me any insights into the problem. (What is your opinion on this matter?) As for the singularity at x=0, I am thinking of finding $y(\epsilon)$ using $$y(x) = y_0 + \frac{x^2}{16}\left(\alpha y_0^3 - 3y_0^2 + 2y_0\right) $$ and then using standard Runge-Kutta to iterate upto the boundary point of the integration. I'm not sure if that falls under method 1 or 2.

Comment: With regard to my previous post, I wasn't actually referring to $y_{0}$ but rather I was referring to the notation $y\_ $ in the boundary condition given by $ y(x) \rightarrow y \_ \equiv 0\ \text{as}\ x \rightarrow \infty $. The notation $y \_$ seems to indicate that y tends to 0 from below the x-axis. But, according to figure 3 on page 7 of the relevant paper, y tends to 0 from above the x-axis.

Comment: My other question was about the infinity in the boundary condition $ y(x) \rightarrow y \_ \equiv 0\ \text{as}\ x \rightarrow \infty $. I was wondering if I should use some large value of x like $10^6$, i.e.  $y(10^6) = 0$ to find the error at every iteration of my shooting algorithm.

Comment: @failexam I totally agree with your professor. Knowing how to solve numerical problems on your own is a very useful skill to have (especially if you are a physicist). Your approach seems fine (this is essentially method 2, but with more accurate initial conditions). I think the notation is just a way to denote the value $\Phi = 0$. I don’t think it means anything special here.

Comment: To find a good stopping criterion for the shoot-match I suggest you play around with the problem (solve, output, plot!) and see what happens when the initial value is to low/ too high. I suspect the solution will either 1) blow up pretty fast or 2) converge to the critical point (given by the solution to the qubic equation on the right hand side of your ODE). For example if 1) happens then you just stop the integration when $y>y_{\rm max}$ or $y<-y_{\rm max}$ where $y_{\rm max}$ is some reasonably large value (say $10$ or $100$).

Comment: btw integrating out to $x=10^6$ seems way to large. I would start with $x=10,50,100$ first and see if I can make it work. The ODE does not seems to be stable to perturbations around $y=0$ so numerical noise can make it blow up it is slightly perturbed away from it. But if the solution is close to $y=0$ at $x=10$ and $x=20$ then you have most likely found the correct initial condition. This is just a guess, you will have to play around with it to learn more about it.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for all the help! I was wondering if you might spare some time to answer a few additional questions. After I implement the forward shooting method, I have to back shoot using the following equations: $y(R) = y_{\infty} \frac{K_{1}(R)}{R}$ and $y'(R) = - y_{\infty} \frac{K_{2}(R)}{R}$. I was wondering where the equations come from. Also, I was wondering if these things are discussed in any textbooks along with the relevant codes and data visualisation software because I'm implementing this in Java using scratchy knowledge from the internet and forums.